# react-native-maps user location pointer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

My react native project code looks like this:

```
  const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
  
  const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
  const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.003;  
  const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

  const mapView = useRef(null)

  const onLocationChange = async (region) => {

    const pstn = region.nativeEvent.coordinate;

    mapView.current?.animateToRegion(
      {
        latitude: pstn.latitude,
        longitude: pstn.longitude,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      }, 
    1000)
  }
  
  <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
        style={styles.map}
        ref={c => mapView.current = c}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: coordinates.latitude,
          longitude: coordinates.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: coordinates.latitudeDelta,
          longitudeDelta: coordinates.longitudeDelta
        }}
        onUserLocationChange={onLocationChange}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        minZoomLevel={15}   
        maxZoomLevel={20}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={false}
        moveOnMarkerPress={false}
        toolbarEnabled={false}
        rotateEnabled={true}
        loadingEnabled={true}
        mapType={'standard'}
   >
          <MapViewDirections
            origin={...}
            destination={...}
            waypoints={...}
            ...
          />
   </MapView>
```

I have a question to ask.

[image]

We need the map to direct user to a designated location (destination). A direction routes is successfully generated, but we need pointer to look like the one in the animation above.

How do I achieve this?